# Connect a TM1627 to ESP32

Tags: esp32, 7-segment

I want to control a 7 segment display that has a TM1637 integrated with an ESP32.

Some time ago I created a layout that used an ESP12e but I need more GPIO pins so I'm switching over to an ESP32.

This was how I had it hooked up:

```
CLK -> GPOI14
DIO -> GPIO12
```

I think I did it this way because I had to use the special CLK pin tou can see in [this](https://simba-os.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/esp12e-pinout.png) pinout.

Only I don't know if I need to hook them up with special pins on the ESP32. I can't find a good tutorial and I don't have the parts yet to test with.

Do you guys know which pin(s) are suitable for the TM1637?

Comment: any. https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TM1637. io 14 on esp8266 can be SPI CLK,  for your connection it was gpio

Comment: It says I can connect it to any gpio, do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label CLK on esp8266 is in a context of SPI pins CLK, MISO, MOSI, SS. You had no reason to connect TM1637 CLK to this pin, since with TM1637 you can use any GPIO pins of the MCU for CLK and DIO.

Comment: Shouldn't `TM1637 can use any GPIO pins for CLK and DIO` be `ESP32 can use any GPIO pins for CLK and DIO`?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: IMO still a bit misleading, in my understanding the ESP32 is the active component controlling the TM1637 using any of it's pins to do that.

Comment: the protocol is determined by the sensor. it it would be SPI you could use only spi pins of the mcu for that sensor. I answer in a context of the question, adding more refinements doesn't help readability.